# de-serialization problems

Tags: java, serialization, jbpm

We have a production system that uses a lot of Serialization. What be basically do is store an object called ProcessData in the jbpm database as byte array. Thus this is serialized.

Consider the following Object.

```
public class ProcessData implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4859440951531011062L;

  public void getX() {
    //not important
  }
}
```

Now lets say we have this object stored in the JBPM database as byte array and we are using this in production.

Now later we want to upgrade this ProcessData object with a new data

```
public class ProcessData implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4859440951531011062L;

  public void getX() {
    //not important
  }

  public void getY() {
    //not important
  }
}
```

Now the problem is when JBPM loads the `old` stored ProcessData object, we get an exception
`Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: my.package.ProcessData; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6651422488035743444, local class serialVersionUID = -7966721901330644987`

Now my question is, how can we solve this problem? How can we make read the serialized object and sort of transform it in this new class. Is it even possible?
Remember that we have limited control over the JBPM library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the sample code in either case, since in your example you are defining the serialVersionUID (this is good) and it is the same before and after, but in your error, the UID's are different.  For this to occur, the UID is either not defined (thus generated), or has been changed between versions.  The generated case would also cause a change between versions since the class signatures are different.

In either case, this would be the expected behaviour.

It looks like the real code being run doesn't actually match your example.  To load the old code, you will have to set the UID in the new version to match the one that already exists in the persisted classes (6651422488035743444L).  Also, it is simpler to manage the UID's if you use simple numbers, like versions 1,2,3.

Comment: No the sample code is exactly that. Sample code. However, I can ensure you that the `serialVersionUID` is exactly same.

Comment: Perhaps the UID was not declared correctly and thus isn't actually used in one of the versions.  If you have access to .class files of both the old and new versions you can run serialver against them to confirm that the UID is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Lets say for the case of argument that the serialVersionUID is the same, and ignore this exception. Is it possible to change a class (By only adding methods, not changing names) and then de-serialize it to load the "old" one in the new class?

Comment: From reading your comments, bottom line: If I add methods I am fine. If I rename or delete methods I am screwed? Given UID is the same.

Comment: No, if you declare the UID in the class, the methods will make no difference to the ability to serialize.  This only affects the generated UID, which is irrelevant if you explicitly declare one.  If you have declared the UID, you can't get a UID mismatch.  You can still potentially get the exception for other reasons, but the reported error indicates a UID mismatch.